# Uncaught Type Error: Polymer is not a function when importing paper-input element

Tags: html, polymer

I am importing `polymer.html`, `paper-input.html`, `core-input.html` but i am still getting the error that Polymer is not a function. What am I missing?

section of the imports below:

```
<script src="../components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/core-input/core-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Comment: Is this code in your `index.html`? You definitely have Polymer downloaded to `../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html`?

Comment: sure they are in index.html i downloaded the starter project from https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html then i just played around with the index.html

Comment: OK, you are potentially mixing versions here. You might be using Polymer 0.5 but you are importing `paper-input` which is a Polymer 1.0 element and `core-input` which is a Polymer 0.5 element. I suggest going [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/) and adding the Polymer starter kit which will get you up and running with Polymer 1.0

Comment: Thank you Ben Thomas that was a good head start. Have picked up and its working

Answer (score 0):

try this.importHref if the error is being thrown on Polymer.importHref

Sometimes the documentation doesn't always match their demos.

if it is being thrown on things like your paper-input try check that it is the correct directory